# Ebay API - How to get an item's ancestor/root category?

Tags: ebay-api

I'm retrieving the item info of many items using `getMultipleItems` in the Shopping API, and I need to find-out the items' root category. In the US site (0), the root categories are here: http://www.isoldwhat.com/getcats/fullcategorytree.php

How can I tell which of these an item belongs to (for example, "Computers/Tablets & Networking")? Can I do it within `getMultipleItems` (or `getSingleItem`) or do I need another call?

It seems like a short question, but this problem is shared with my use of the Amazon API to which I've been doing extensive research and I decided to resolve it on my eBay end. The "problem" is determining the selling fee, which can be done on Amazon's side, by getting the `ProductGroup` of the item, or by using eBay's root categories, and matching either one to the fee table Amazon defined for it's commission rates. In this case, there's not a lot of turn-out to refer to here to show I looked everything up.

The `getCategoryInfo` and related `category-info-searching` doesn't pertain to particular items. I get a `<primarycategoryid>` N/V pair in my item responses, but (I'm pretty sure) that's a leaf category (mapping 10,000+ leaf categories [even just the fraction I would use] to Amazon's product group-specific fee table would be a hell of a pain).

Again, how do I trace an `<item>` to it's ancestor/root category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trace the root of a category via the *PrimaryCategoryIDPath* field that is returned when calling GetMultipleItems.

Keep in mind that this information is not returned unless you have specified *Details* in the *IncludeSelector* field as part of your request.

More information on *PrimaryCategoryIDPath* can be found [here](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/shopping/docs/CallRef/GetMultipleItems.html#Response.Item.PrimaryCategoryIDPath).